# Specific route is not being invoked in Blazor Server controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor web assembly, I have a controller as shown here in the server project:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public BlogController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetPagedBlogs")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Blog>>> GetPagedBlogs()
    {
        var blogs = _context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ToList();
        return Ok(blogs ;
    }
}
```

When I try to send a request to

```
https://mydomain/api/blog/GetPagedBlogs
```

it doesn't reach this action method. But if I replace `[HttpGet("GetPagedBlogs")]` with just `[HttpGet]` and send request to `https://mydomain/api/blog`, then it reaches the action method.

What am I missing?

I am using .NET 7 and here is my `program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: To enable attribute routing for ASP.NET Core Web API, I believe you need to use `builder.Services.AddControllers();` (instead of `AddControllersWithViews();` - that's for MVC) in your `program.cs` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please post this as an answer

Comment: misunderstood the question in the former answer, just as marc said, AddControllers() is for Web Api,however, as far as I konw,AddControllersWithViews() would contain both all servics in AddControllers() and the services for view which are not reqired in your project,would it work now with AddControllers()?(it performed the same on myside,i'm really  curious about it ) ,would it work with the attribute [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable the attribute-based routing in ASP.NET Core Web API, you need to replace:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

(*this is for ASP.NET Core MVC - where you have controllers with views*)

with

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

to enable Web API controllers with attribute-based routing.